# C How can i compare if a string is 0d0a in hex

Tags: c, string, hex

I need to check string values and if a string with value 0d0a in hex comes i need to break while loop.

How to check this since those are unprintable characters ?

Comment: Could you elaborate more your question ?

Comment: How can I check if hex value of a string is (0d0a)    Dont know how to elaborate more

Comment: does `memcpy()` helps?

Comment: `strcmp(my_string, "\x0d\x0a");`  Consider instead `strcmp(my_string, "\r\n")` if your intent is to check for a CR+NL pair.

Comment: Being printable has nothing to do with this. I suppose you are confused because you cannot say `if(code == 'a')`, perhaps? Just do a simple `strncmp`, or similar, where you have a `#define CODE "0d0a"`. In this way, simply compare that constant string with your received string. Note that `CODE` will be `0 d 0 a \n`.

Comment: OK i'll write a proper answer

Comment: @sherrellbc yes I tried to write rather such  if(code == 'a'). But strcmp with hex values works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a string consists of just those two characters:

```
if ( 0 == strcmp(my_string, "\x0d\x0a") )
{
    // action to take if it matches
}
```

If your intent is to look for CR-NL pairs then `"\r\n"` is equivalent (in ASCII encoding) and documents that a bit more clearly.

Comment: if you want it faster, how about \*(WORD\*)my_string == '0xad'.  My bad, i just saw will's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

First, although they are not printable, you can represent those values with the escape character '\'. In this case, the string you want can be written like "\r\n".
So, returning to your question, there are several ways to check for this string, for example:

- Use string comparison functions, like strcmp, against "\r\n"
- Check for the independent bytes:

  ```
  (str[0] == 0xd) && (str[1] == 0xa)
  ```

  note that 0xd is the same as '\r', and 0xa can be replaced by '\n'.
- You can check for the 16 bit number 0x0a0d (Asuming a little endian CPU like Intel's):

  ```
  ((uint16*)str)[0] == 0x0a0d
  ```

  where uint16 must be defined as a 16 bit integer. When using this option the memory reserved for the string must be always of size >= 2.

Edited (thanks to Matt): Some platforms enforce the aligned memory access, for those platforms the last method will fail if the string address is not 2 bytes aligned. The x86 and x64 platforms don´t have this problem.

Comment: The latter option may cause undefined behaviour due to alignment issues (as well as the endianness issue)

Comment: Thanks Matt, I edited my answer to take note of this. I agree that the latter method is not portable, but it can give to the beginners an idea about how memory is structured.

Comment: Its not a problem on Intel.  Unaligned access is not even that much slower these days.  On Intel, aligned or unaligned, ((uint16*)str)[0] == 0x0a0d is going to be several times faster than strcmp or memcmp.  If you look at msvc disassembly you see it using this optimization a lot.